# forEach not working for response.data in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, components

I am trying to loop through a response from a data file however, I am getting an error I can't debug or see why it doesn't work. I had tried the forEach and map within a function but it failed just the same.

I had tried the forEach and map within a function but it failed just the same.

```
class GetTiles extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tileData: {},
            dataLoaded: false
        };
    }

    loadData() {
        axios("assets/data/home.json")
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    tileData: response.data.titles,
                    dataLoaded: true
                });
                console.log("Local Tiles Ajax Call: Success");
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("Local Tiles Ajax Call", err);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadData();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Tile title="1" />
                {this.state.tileData.map((item, index) => (
                    <p key={index}>Hello!</p>
                ))}
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default GetTiles;
```

Please note I know it doesn't make sense why I am doing this, but it is to help me understand and debug the issue/Get something working.

```
{
    "_id": "home",
    "titles": [
        {
            "type": "app",
            "title": [
                {
                    "text": "Demo",
                    "locale": "en-gb"
                }
            ],
            "data": {
                "app_name": "lorem",
                "category": "demo"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "app",
            "title": [
                {
                    "text": "Demo 2",
                    "locale": "en-gb"
                }
            ],
            "data": {
                "app_name": "ipsum",
                "category": "sports"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am wanting to be able to target titles within the JSON to get data from it and print out data for each onto the page.

The Error:
A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See *** for more information.

Comment: _" I am getting an error"_ - what kind of an error? What is the error message?

Comment: The error is no help, sorry should of added it still. The error is:
A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See *** for more information.

Comment: Initially (based on that small snip of code) `this.state.tileData` will likely be an empty array or `undefined` depending on how you've set up your state. You need to check for that in your render method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial state `tileData` is an object. You can't `forEach` or `map` over an object but that's what you've asked the code to do. It will try to iterate over that state property on the first render which is probably what that error is.

Change

```
this.state = { tileData: {} }
```

to

```
this.state = { tileData: [] }
```

and then add a condition to your render to return something else if the array is empty, something like:

```
render() {
  if (!this.state.titleData.length) return <div>No data</div>
  return this.state.tileData.map(tile => etc
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was the solution! I thought it would be something some I just couldn't see. As simple as using {} when I should of used [].

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to change `this.state = {tileData: {}, ...}` to `this.state = {tileData: [],...}`.

Your first lines should look like:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { tileData: [], dataLoaded: false };
}
```